# How can I Ask the user for a Path and then put the same Path as a Directory for a Directoryinfo?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello and thank you in advance.
What I'm trying to do is to display all the files of a directory.
The path of the directory is included in the code.

What I want to do is to ask the user for a directory and then use the path of that directory instead of this: `("*.*")`

**C# CODE**

```
protected void ListFiles(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/"));
    System.IO.FileInfo[] fileNames = dirInfo.GetFiles("*.*");

    foreach (System.IO.FileInfo fi in fileNames)
    {
        listbox1.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} | {1} | {2} KB", fi.Name, fi.LastAccessTime, fi.Length));
    }
}
```

**ASP CODE**

```
<asp:ListBox ID="listbox1" runat="server" OnLoad="ListFiles"Height="500" Width="600" Font-Bold="true"></asp:ListBox>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your issue is not clear. You cannot _download_ all files from a user's directory for security reasons. Instead the user must upload each file to the server.

Comment: This code already displays them.

Comment: Instead of a path embedded in the code I want to be able to have a browse button that let me chose the directory I want to know the info about(files included ecc...).

Comment: So you want to let the user select a directory from the server?

Comment: Yep, Without dowloading the files. Just displaying them.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want the user to select a directory on the server, [try this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/ASP/Components/WebbasedfilebrowserC.htm) from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492812/browse-files-server-side-in-asp-net) or [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/301328/ASP-NETUser-Control-File-Browser).

If you want the user to select a directory on his machine, use the HTMLInputFile Class of the .NET framework.